# How to register custom webcontext path for metrics in Helidon 3x?

Tags: helidon

How to pass custom webcontext path like /ahi/metric for metrics in Helidon 3x?

In 2.x we were using below code snippet which is deprecated in 3.x

```
MetricsSupport metrics = MetricsSupport.builder().webContext("/ahi/metric").build();
```

Comment: Hi and welcome here. Maybe your question is out of the scope of SO. Here, you have to submit code you have written, with which you encounter a technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

When an API is deprecated, the documentation would/should normally state its replacement (also with an example in many cases).

Helidon documents the replacement API for [MetricsSupport.builder()](https://helidon.io/docs/latest/apidocs/io.helidon.metrics/io/helidon/metrics/MetricsSupport.html#builder()) in the documentation as:

> Deprecated, for removal: This API element is subject to removal in a
> future version. Use MetricsSupport.builder() instead.

So the replacement for the deprecated API would be:
[MetricsSupport.builder()](https://helidon.io/docs/latest/apidocs/io.helidon.metrics.serviceapi/io/helidon/metrics/serviceapi/MetricsSupport.html#builder()). This is a very subtle change in the package and hence it is not evident from the HTML doc text alone unless you follow the link to the serviceapi package. The java doc is more clear in this aspect:

> @deprecated Use {@link
> io.helidon.metrics.serviceapi.MetricsSupport#builder()} instead.

So answer to your question is:

```
MetricsSupport.builder()
              .restServiceSettings(
                   MetricsSupport.builder()
                                 .restServiceSettings(
                                      RestServiceSettings.builder()
                                             .webContext("/ahi/metric"))
                                             .build())
               .build();
```

PS: It is always faster to view the docs inline by having the sources-jar downloaded into your local IDE setup to avoid a round trip to the internet for viewing docs.